# GLSL + OpenGL Moving away from state machine

Tags: opengl, glsl

I started moving one of my projects away from fixed pipeline, so to try things out I tried to write a shader that would simply pass the OpenGL matrices and transform the vertex with that and then start calculating my own once I knew that worked. I thought this would be a simple task but even this will not work.

I started out with this shader for normal fixed pipeline:

```
void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = gl_ModelViewProjectionMatrix  * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

I then changed it to this:

```
uniform mat4 model_matrix;
uniform mat4 projection_matrix;

void main(void)
{
    gl_Position = model_matrix * projection_matrix * gl_Vertex;
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
}
```

I then retrieve the OpenGL matrices like this and pass them to the shader with this code:

```
 [material.shader bindShader];

 GLfloat modelmat[16];
        GLfloat projectionmat[16];
        
        glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX, modelmat);
        glGetFloatv(GL_PROJECTION_MATRIX, projectionmat);
        
            
        glUniformMatrix4fv([material.shader getUniformLocation:"model_matrix"], 1, GL_FALSE, modelmat);
        glUniformMatrix4fv([material.shader getUniformLocation:"projection_matrix"], 1, GL_FALSE, projectionmat );
... Draw Stuff
```

For some reason this does not draw anything (I am 95% positive those matrices are correct before I pass them btw) Any Ideas?

Comment: Why do you retrieve matrices from OpenGL and then pass them back to it? Yes, OpenGL-3 core depreceated matric math functions, but not to make you implementing some loopback. You're supposed to do the math yourself or use a dedicated matrix math library.

Comment: The OpenGL state machine is in no way tied to the fixed function pipeline. Also with programmable shaders instead of fixed function OpenGL remains a state machine (in this case the bound shaders, textures and buffers define the GL state).

Comment: The matrix order is wrong in the second version. Should be `projection*modelview*vertex`.

Comment: @datenwolf  I was just doing this to try it out. It obviously does not make sense, but I could not try calculating my own matrices till I got this working.

Comment: @Itjax Thanks! I did not know that it was order dependant.

Comment: @JustinMeiners Absolutely. Matrix multiplication is non-commutative (the order matters). That's what makes them so great for geometric transformations, you can simplify an infinite number of transformations into a single transformation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that my order of matrix multiplication was wrong. I was not aware that the operations were not commutative.

The correct order should be:

```
projection * modelview * vertex
```

Thanks to ltjax and doug65536

Answer (score 2):

For the matrix math, try using an external library, such as [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/). They also have some basic [examples](http://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.5/code.html) on how to create the necessary matrices and do the projection * view * model transform.

Answer (score 0):

Use OpenGL 3.3's shading language. OpenGL 3.3 is roughly comparable to DirectX10, hardware-wise.

Don't use the deprecated functionality. Almost everything in your first `void main` example is deprecated. You must explicity declare your inputs and outputs if you expect to use the high-performance code path of the drivers. Deprecated functionality is also far more likely to be full of driver bugs.

Use the newer, more explicit style of declaring inputs and outputs and set them in your code. It really isn't bad. I thought this would be ugly but it actually was pretty easy (I wish I had just done it earlier).

FYI, the last time I looked at a lowest common denominator for OpenGL (2012), it was OpenGL 3.3. Practically all video cards from AMD and NVidia that have any gaming capability will have OpenGL 3.3. And they have for a while, so any code you write now for OpenGL 3.3 will work on a typical low-end or better GPU.